# Document-Based App Examples

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, ide, document-based

I'm building an Integrated Development Environment (IDE) application for Mac OS X.

When creating a new Mac OS X Cocoa Application should I select (check) Create a Document-Based Application?

What are some examples of document-based apps?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you'll probably want your IDE to be a document-based app because the [Document-Based App Programming Guide for Mac](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/DocBasedAppProgrammingGuideForOSX/Introduction/Introduction.html) says, "Document-based apps handle multiple documents ... and often display more than one document at a time." For an IDE app, each document could be a source file.

### Examples of Document-Based Apps

- [Xcode](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/)
- [Sketch](http://www.bohemiancoding.com/sketch)
- [Pages](http://www.apple.com/iwork/pages/)